# GMSPolyline with dot pattern between multiple pins

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-polyline, gmsmapview

I'm trying to draw a dotted polyline on GMSMapView. What I've achieved so far is to add a dashed polyline on the map. For which I've written below code:

```
polyLine.strokeWidth = 10
polyLine.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 95/255, green: 89/255, blue: 89/255, alpha: 1.0)
let styles: [GMSStrokeStyle] = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.clear), GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.red)]
let scale = 1.0 / testMap.projection.points(forMeters: 1, at: testMap.camera.target)
let solidLine = NSNumber(value: 10.0 * Float(scale))
let gap = NSNumber(value: 10.0 * Float(scale))        
let span = GMSStyleSpans(polyLine.path!, styles, [solidLine, gap], GMSLengthKind.rhumb)        
polyLine.spans = span
```

With this code, I'm getting a polyline with 10x10 squares as dashes.

For dotted polyline I've tried to set the dot image as one of the solid color in GMSStrokeStyle like below:

```
let styles: [GMSStrokeStyle] = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "dot1.jpg")!)), GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.red)]
```

One more solution I've tried for the same is [here](https://engineering.door2door.io/dotted-polylines-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios-7b21786a0645)

With this solution, the map takes significant amount of time to load and refresh. Because of which the application hangs on loading the map.

What are other approaches to draw a Dotted Polyline on Google Map in ios?

Comment: to avoid lagging and handing issue, you can update polyline on "idleAt " instead of  "didChange".

Comment: Yes. We can definitely use "idleAt" function. But how can we solve the hanging issue on initial map loading? With more than 5 locations on map, It is taking a good 25 seconds of delay to load the map initially.